# Thermography - objects appear hotter than they are

Tags: thermal-radiation

recently I started working with IR thermal camera (Hikvision DS-2TD1217-3/V1) and I have a slight problem. The camera works fine when there are only people in the image, however if I place a hot coffee mug in the image, suddenly everybody has 80 degrees Celsius... why is that? Normally, you would expect that the regions with faces would become darker in the image (because of automatic temperature scaling) when another, much hotter body enters the scene.

Any tips are appreciated.

Also, not sure if it's the right place to post it ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you run a calibration procedure?

Comment: no, and at the same time i don't think it would help. I don't care if the measured temperature is even wrong by 3 or more degrees. I should not get 80 degrees Celsius on my face just because there is something hotter in the image. I think there might be something wrong with the camera software. If i turn on the option to mark areas hotter than 40 degrees Celsius, it only marks the hot mug, but not my face, even though, based on the scale on the side of the screen, my face should be hotter than 40 as well.

Comment: Normally if you body temperature is above 40 you is dead...

Comment: is it possible that there is some sort of automatic rescaling of the temperature? Can you output two images and check what the image is? Additionally, even if the water is 100C, when you pour it into a mug you are not going to get the mug at 80C for more than a few seconds.

Comment: Pro tip: don't have a coffee mug in the image, problem solved.
But seriously- is the only issue with a hot beverage mug, or if anything else is hot in the frame? Might be water vapor from the coffee in the air disturbing the readings.

Comment: could you post an image with the face, with the mug and with the option above 40C? Also include the legend.